# make a list of random predefined valuables (without quotes)

Tags: list, python-3.x, format, raspberry-pi3, single-quotes

I have a program where I generate a list of 64 random letters. Those letters are the predefined variables. I want to use this list to set the pixels of the ledmatrix for my sensehat (raspberry Pi).

I use the set_pixels function. The problem is that the list formatted everything to strings with the added single quotes while the set_pixels function expects a tuple of 3 valuables to define the color of that pixel. If the list would just contain the letters without the quotes, they would get recognized as my predefined variables and everything would work (I guess).

```
s = SenseHat()
display = []
P = (255,0,0)
Z = (0,255,255)

for i in range(64):
  x = random.choice("PZ")
  display.append(x)

s.set_pixels(display)
```

If I add `print(display)` to the code i get something like this:

> ['P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'Z', 'Z', 'P', 'P', 'Z', 'Z', 'P', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'P', 'P', 'Z', 'P', 'Z', 'P', 'Z', 'Z', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'Z', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'P', 'P', 'Z', 'P', 'Z', 'P', 'P', 'Z', 'P', 'Z', 'P', 'Z', 'P', 'Z', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'P', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'P', 'P']

set_pixels works fine if I manually add the same list without the quotes. Adding stuff manually is not really an option since the list needs to be randomly generated.

Any ideas how to format this in the right way?

Comment: Just choose between your variables.  `x = random.choice([P, Z])` The characters `'P'` and `'Z'` are only related to the variables `P` and `Z` in the `locals` mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled around a little more and came up with this simple solution for my problem. I added this if-statement instead of putting the x-value in my list. This seems to work now. If someone would know a more efficient solution, please do elaborate on this.

```
if x == "P":
  display.append(P)
else:
  display.append(Z)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the line:

```
x = random.choice("PZ")
```

to

```
x = random.choice((P, Z))
```

then it will simply substitute `P` for `(255, 0, 0)` and Z for `(0, 255, 255)` (like constants), and return a list of randomly selected colour tuples.